# Typing on my iPhone: how to change input method when typing from an external Bluetooth keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard, bluetooth

I need to type in two languages on my **iPhone** but can only do so easily when typing from Apple's "Magic Keyboard". I am looking for potential ways to make typing on an iPhone easier for *other* Bluetooth keyboards that were not made by nor for Apple devices.

I should be running the **latest iOS software**.

**The Trouble**: For now, after I paired the iPhone with an Always-On Bluetooth keyboard at home, I am forever bound to such keyboard: it won't quit, as the keyboard is powered by a set of AA batteries and there is no switch on it to turn it off, and it won't let me change input method!

### What the "Magic Keyboard" does when paired with iPhone

Thanks to the integration of Apple products, there are two ways:

1. At the far right corner of the Magic Keyboard, there is a key that can show/hide the on-screen keyboard. One can use this interface to switch input method.
2. Moreover, the default "Mac-OS" keyboard shortcut still works: holding <kbd>opt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> shall get me to loop through the input methods

Yet, I only have bought one pair of Magic Keyboard and have kept it at work. Over the years, I should have a good number of generic Bluetooth keyboards, 2 among which are fancy mechanical switch ones. Unfortunately, they are "generic Bluetooth keyboards" ==>

### What generic Bluetooth keyboards do? And, can we avoid buying

Well, when typing, I did not find a way to summon the on-screen keyboard at all. This bans all graphical interface tweaks: there is simply no button to click on.

- **Question 1**: Can I devise finger swipes to change input methods? I have only two in total.

Then, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> does not register on iPhone. This may have to do with how these generic Bluetooth keyboards are dealing with issuing keystrokes, and I wonder if there is a walk-around? Say:

- **Question 2**: Is it possible to **define** keyboard shortcuts for iPhone to loop through input methods?
- **Question 3**: Or, can I spare a <kbd>F1</kbd> key if key-combination is not allowed, solely for iOS to change input method.

Comment: You can always turn off bluetooth in the phone temporarily so the keyboard is unavailable.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, thank you for mentioning the on/off switch for Bluetooth. It is easy-to-use enough, but won't work well when I am home ==> I do need to maintain a number of Bluetooth speakers + headsets for audio connection. Shutting off Bluetooth completely will also shut down my connection to those speakers. Ctrl + Space did helped!

Comment: I rolled this back because the answer doesn’t need to be added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to switch layouts in iOS is always Control plus Space (not Alt/Opt). It should work on arbitrary keyboards with these two keys.

There’s no way to change this shortcut in iOS as far as I know.

Comment: Indeed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>worked! I should forget to test `Ctrl + Space` on the keyboard! (I swapped the Capslock and Ctrl keys on almost all my keyboards, and it is my absent-mindedness that brought up the original long question. Should have tested Ctrl + Space from day 1. (This problem has bugged me for years, I have to confess.)